# QT 32 and 64 bit rpms installed. failed dependencies. which to use?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, 32bit-64bit, rpm

Please help me figure out what is going on with my system. When I type

```
rpm -qa|grep qt
```

I get:

```
qt5-rpm-macros-5.6.2-1.el7.noarch
qt-x11-4.8.5-13.el7.i686
qt5-qtxmlpatterns-5.6.2-1.el7.x86_64
qt-creator-4.1.0-3.el7.x86_64
qt5-qtbase-gui-5.6.2-1.el7.x86_64
qt-4.8.5-13.el7.i686
qt5-qttools-libs-clucene-5.6.2-1.el7.x86_64
qt-x11-4.8.5-13.el7.x86_64
qt5-qttools-libs-designercomponents-5.6.2-1.el7.x86_64
qt5-qtdeclarative-5.6.2-1.el7.x86_64
qt5-qtdoc-5.6.2-1.el7.noarch
qt5-qtquickcontrols-5.6.2-1.el7.x86_64
dbusmenu-qt-0.9.2-7.el7.x86_64
qt-4.8.5-13.el7.x86_64
qt5-qttools-libs-help-5.6.2-1.el7.x86_64
qt5-qtwebchannel-5.6.2-1.el7.x86_64
qt5-qtbase-common-5.6.2-1.el7.noarch
qt5-qttools-common-5.6.2-1.el7.noarch
polkit-qt-0.103.0-10.el7_0.x86_64
qt5-qtwebkit-5.6.2-1.el7.x86_64
qt5-qtbase-devel-5.6.2-1.el7.x86_64
qt5-qtbase-5.6.2-1.el7.x86_64
qt5-qtsensors-5.6.2-1.el7.x86_64
qt5-qttools-libs-designer-5.6.2-1.el7.x86_64
qt-settings-19-23.5.el7.noarch
qt-devel-4.8.5-13.el7.i686
qt5-qtscript-5.6.2-1.el7.x86_64
qt-creator-data-4.1.0-3.el7.noarch
qt5-qtlocation-5.6.2-1.el7.x86_64
```

And a few more commands and results:

```
arch = x86_64
qmake --version = QMake version 2.01 Using Qt version 4.8.5 in /usr/lib
```

My confusion:

1. Why are both 32 and 64 bit rpms of qt installed?
2. Why do I see qt5 rpms installed on a 4.8 system?
3. How do I know which rpms to install when installing new libraries, 32 or 64?

I am asking because I tried to install the phonon 64 bit version and get error from pro file:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib64/libphonon.so when searching for -lphonon
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lphonon
```

And when I tried to install 32 bit version I get dependency issues on 12 .so files, for example:

```
libpulse-mainloop-glib.so.0 is needed by phonon-4.6.0-10.el7.i686
libpulse-mainloop-glib.so.0(PULSE_0) is needed by phonon-4.6.0-10.el7.i686
libpulse.so.0 is needed by phonon-4.6.0-10.el7.i686
libgstreamer-0.10.so.0 is needed by phonon-backend-gstreamer-2:4.6.3-3.el7.i686
```

Which I cant locate anywhere on my system. Please fill in my gaps and explain what I'm seeing if possible

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: thanks for letting me know! so hard to keep all these sites straight. Do I need to close this question or something then? I've heard thats bad form to do though, no?